how to copy settings of ObjectMapper
I have an ObjectMapper, which is considered the standard one, with several options set. It is defined like this:
ObjectMapper standardMapper = new ObjectMapper();
standardMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
standardMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategies.LOWER_CAMEL_CASE);
final SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addSerializer(Double.class, new MyDoubleSerializer());
standardMapper.registerModule(module);
standardMapper.registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule(JsonCreator.Mode.PROPERTIES));

Later I have two ObjectMappers: the standardMapper from above and a specificMapper which can have any customization possible. The goal is to return an ObjectMapper that has all the customziation of specificMapper, but if they conflict with the ones from standardMapper, then standardMapper customziation should be used.
So I tried to write it like this:
public static ObjectMapper getMergedMapper(ObjectMapper standardMapper, ObjectMapper specificMapper) {
    ObjectMapper mergedMapper = specificMapper.copy();
    mergedMapper.setSerializationInclusion(standardMapper.getSerializationInclusion()); // getter does not exist
    mergedMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(standardMapper.getPropertyNamingStrategy());
    mergedMapper.registerModules(standardMapper.getRegisteredModules()); // getter does not exist
}

But since there are no getters for SerializationInclusion and RegisteredModules, what can I do? I know I could copy-paste part of the code from above (like setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL)), but there must be a better solution...
